# How to receive multiple strings from a user and add those string to an array in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, c-strings

I am beginner in c++ and I have a question,

I want to receive multiple strings from a user, and add each of these strings to an array in c++.

For example:

input:

```
cin >> "sara"; 

cin >> "jack";

cin >> "john";
```

output:

```
string_of_names = {"sara", "jack", "john"}
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    const int N = 200;
    char string[N];


    for (int i=0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter a name: " << endl;
        cin >> string;

    }

    cout << string;
    return 0;
}
```

But in this case, I think every string gets replaced by the new string.

Comment: Please post what you have tried, preferably a [mcve].

Comment: Does the tag c-strings mean you are to explicitly use character array instead of `std::string`? Also include example of what you did so far.

Comment: Split up those tasks. Either step should be explained by any halfway decent C++ tutorial then. Note that Stack Overflow doesn't want to teach languages from scratch, take the [tour] and read [ask] to get an introduction.

Answer (score 4):

Did you try using c++ stl's container std::vector?

This will do.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    //this is a dynamically resizable container that works like an array
    //with O(1) index access complexity
    vector<string> dynamicArray; 

    string inputString;

    cin>>inputString; //"sara"
    dynamicArray.push_back(inputString); //add to the vector

    cin>>inputString; //"jack"
    dynamicArray.push_back(inputString); //add to the vector   

    cin>>inputString; //"john"
    dynamicArray.push_back(inputString); //add to the vector  

    //view the elements of the vector
    for(int i=0; i < dynamicArray.size(); i++){
        cout<<dynamicArray[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, I'm answering on the basis that you cannot use common C++ features, like `std::vector` and `std::string`. For some reason you are stuck with that unfortunately all too common dialect of C++ which is just C with C++ I/O bolted on. For the proper C++ answer see xlr8's post.

First thing to realise is that you need a two dimensional array of char. One dimension because a string has multiple chars, and the second dimension because you want multiple strings. So

```
const int NUM_STRINGS = 3;
const int MAX_STRING_SIZE = 200;
char string_array[NUM_STRINGS][MAX_STRING_SIZE];
```

Then you have to adjust your code so that you say which string in the string array you are interested in.

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_STRINGS; i++)
{
    cout << "Enter a name: " << endl;
    cin >> string_array[i];
}
```

And finally you also need a loop to output the string array

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_STRINGS; i++)
{
    cout << string_array[i] << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Side note: `cin >> string_array[i];` stops as soon as it finds whitespace, so it is incapable of handling names like Sally Anne. If you need this support, [use `cin.getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline).

Comment: can I use cin.getline() for two dimensional arrays?

Comment: Like this `cin.getline(string_array[i], MAX_STRING_SIZE);`. But really you are using `getine` with a one dimensional array. `string_array` is two dimensional but `string_array[i]` is one dimensional, and can be used anywhere a one dimensional array is legal.